# Why does python show 0.2 + 0.2 as 0.4?

Tags: python, floating-point

I think I understood why 0.1 + 0.2 is 0.30000000000000004, but following the same logic why is 0.2 + 0.2 = 0.4? Isn't 0.2 a value you can't get in binary base?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's `'0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625'` actually. The default representation still rounds.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you need to explain why python is printing it out as 0.4. Is python rounding to a certain number of digits?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for your answer: why does python rounds that to 0.4 but doesn't round 0.2 + 0.1 to 0.3?

Comment: Note also that this "works" for any addition of the form `x + x`: e.g., the result of `1.234 + 1.234` will be printed as `2.468`.  That's essentially because if `x` is the closest representable binary float to a real number `v`, then (ignoring overflow and subnormals) `x + x` must be the closest representable binary float to the real number `v + v`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson This is also true for subnormals.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: True.  It's easier to run into problems with precision with subnormals, though.  E.g., `1.6e-322 + 1.6e-322` will display as `3.16e-322` rather than `3.2e-322`.  I should have been clearer and set a limit on the length of the decimal strings being used: e.g., for any `x` that's the closest float to a real value exactly expressible in 15 or fewer decimal digits, and then you need to replace that 15 with something smaller (and variable) for subnormals.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Oh, I see what you meant now. Thanks for this insight.

Answer (score 2):

To get `0.2` you need to sum binary fractions of 2. Here are the first few:

```
Decimal   Binary
1       = 1
0.5     = 0.1
0.25    = 0.01
0.125   = 0.001
0.0625  = 0.0001
```

So, to get 0.2, you need to sum

```
0.125
+ 0.0625 = 0.187500
```

The next binary fraction is 0.03125. If I sum that, it's too large (> 0.2), so is the next one 0.015625. The following one, 0.0078125 is ok, so

```
0.125 + 0.0625 + 0.0078125 = 0.195312
```

and so on. So we have skipped 0.5 (gives a 0), and 0.25 (another 0), we did use 0.125 (1) and 0.0625 (1). Again, we skipped two values (00) and used the next one (1)...

But, whatever we do, we cannot represent 0.2 with an exact binary numner. we have to continue and continue... If we don't continue infinitely, the representation is not exactly 0.2...

Now try with 0.25 or 0.25...

Now why are we seeing different things in modern Pythons (>= 2.7, and >= 3), this comes from an internal change:

> In versions prior to Python 2.7 and Python 3.1, Python rounded this
>   value to 17 significant digits, giving ‘0.10000000000000001’. In
>   current versions, Python displays a value based on the shortest
>   decimal fraction that rounds correctly back to the true binary value,
>   resulting simply in ‘0.1’.

See [this article](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), bottom of the page.